# Ionic 4 Slides - Set An Initial Slide

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides

Is it possible to select a slide to display with a focus on as the initial one? I have an array of items to display in Ionic slides, and I want to "preselect" (= put focus on the slide) based on preferences but keep the order.

I have read the Ionic documentation, but I am probably missing something. So far it looks I would need to use the `slideTo` function in the constructor of the page, but I was looking for a directive to use directly in the html template.

Thank you for any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.html

```
 <ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

.ts

```
 slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 2,
    speed: 400
  };
```

all the options are here http://idangero.us/swiper/api/